# General error: 1364 Field 'avatar' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having a strange error, followed by a lot of data behind it and I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the error :

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 624: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field ‘avatar’ doesn’t have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (admin, contact@xxxxxxx.com, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, admin, 1, 2016-03-01 13:34:11, 2016-03-01 13:34:11))
```

If I refer to the code at line 624 like shown, here is what is written in the file "connection.php" :

```
throw new QueryException(
                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

EDIT : Here are the lines that come after, you will see that there is a HUGE amount of them and I don't know if it helps :

```
in Connection.php line 624
at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('usernamevalue', 'emailvalue@email.com', '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'admin', '1', '2016-03-01 13:57:40', '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 580
at Connection->run('insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('usernamevalue', 'emailvalue@email.com', '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'admin', '1', '2016-03-01 13:57:40', '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 363
at Connection->statement('insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('usernamevalue', 'emailvalue@email.com', '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'admin', '1', '2016-03-01 13:57:40', '2016-03-01 13:57:40')) in Connection.php line 320
at Connection->insert('insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('usernamevalue', 'emailvalue@email.com', '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'admin', '1', '2016-03-01 13:57:40', '2016-03-01 13:57:40')) in Processor.php line 30
at Processor->processInsertGetId(object(Builder), 'insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('usernamevalue', 'emailvalue@email.com', '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'admin', '1', '2016-03-01 13:57:40', '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), 'id') in Builder.php line 1725
at Builder->insertGetId(array('name' => 'usernamevalue', 'email' => 'emailvalue@email.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'permission' => 'admin', 'status' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40', 'created_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), 'id')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'insertGetId'), array(array('name' => 'usernamevalue', 'email' => 'emailvalue@email.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'permission' => 'admin', 'status' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40', 'created_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), 'id')) in Builder.php line 933
at Builder->__call('insertGetId', array(array('name' => 'usernamevalue', 'email' => 'emailvalue@email.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'permission' => 'admin', 'status' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40', 'created_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), 'id')) in Model.php line 1609
at Builder->insertGetId(array('name' => 'usernamevalue', 'email' => 'emailvalue@email.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'permission' => 'admin', 'status' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40', 'created_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40'), 'id') in Model.php line 1609
at Model->insertAndSetId(object(Builder), array('name' => 'usernamevalue', 'email' => 'emailvalue@email.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'permission' => 'admin', 'status' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40', 'created_at' => '2016-03-01 13:57:40')) in Model.php line 1579
at Model->performInsert(object(Builder), array()) in Model.php line 1485
at Model->save() in UserRepository.php line 89
at UserRepository->create(array('name' => 'usernamevalue', 'email' => 'emailvalue@email.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$LKucgBKpw4hfAQahVL5tVezYe0Tz84.FacXIIODK9blnJLy0Pa6/e', 'permission' => 'admin', 'status' => '1')) in AdminController.php line 37
at AdminController->save(object(Request), object(UserRepository))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminController), 'save'), array(object(Request), object(UserRepository))) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('save', array(object(Request), object(UserRepository))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AdminController), object(Route), 'save') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AdminController), object(Route), object(Request), 'save') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'Smile\Http\Controllers\Installer\AdminController', 'save') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 701
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in SavableMiddleware.php line 33
at SavableMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Language.php line 25
at Language->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in RequestTracker.php line 40
at RequestTracker->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 43
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 62
```

Comment: Just read the error message properly: you try to insert data into a table and didn't provide a value for a column that doesn't have a default value (`avatar`), so you'll either have to include the column in your insert statement or give the avatar column a default value using HeidiSQL or MySQL Control center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the avatar column doesn't have a default value and your insert command didn't pass a value to the column. You should provide one, you can modify your insert statement to insert an appropriate value to avatar.

```
insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `permission`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`, `avatar`) values (admin, contact@xxxxxxx.com, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, admin, 1, 2016-03-01 13:34:11, 2016-03-01 13:34:11, NULL)
```

OR

set a default value for the `avatar` column on the database.

```
ALTER TABLE foobar CHANGE COLUMN avatar <type>  DEFAULT <default_value>;
```

Comment: Yes but in what file, the same one ?

Comment: Can you check the type of the column 'avatar' and rewrite the insert statement to insert something there?

Comment: Look where the variable `$query` is being defined.

Comment: Hummm... It is a code I bought on CodeCanyon and I have no support from them... I edited my original post, can you check and tell me if you have more clue on where I should edit that ?
THANKS !

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to set a default value directly on the database table, can you do that?

Comment: Yes but when I refresh the page to access the website, it comes back to the page where I have to set the username, password and email of the admin and then when I validate, it puts back the value of the avatar column to "NONE" :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105016/discussion-between-william-janoti-and-frenchynyc).

Answer (score 2):

Is there an avatar column in your table and you might also quote your values.

Comment: Indeed there is a column avatar in the table... However I don't know what to add and where...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you created the avatar field with default value none and not null. But you did not specify the avatar field fillable in your model. Try adding the following line in your model.

```
protected $fillable = ['avatar'];
```